# cv2.threshold() error (-210)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm new to Python.

I want to define text rotation with help of Fourier transformation.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

img = cv2.imread ('Text_rot.bmp', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
afterFourier =  np.log (np.abs(np.fft.fft2 (img)))
ret1, th1 = cv2.threshold (afterFourier, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

But this code fails with:

```
ret1, th1 = cv2.threshold (afterFourier, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
error: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:783: error: (-210)
```

Why does that cause a "-210" error?

Comment: that's the complete error ? i hope not. but usually fft works on float data, while [cv2.threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cv2.threshold) wants uchar

Comment: @berak: It's the complete error

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The OpenCV [error codes](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#error) can be looked up in [`types_c.h`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/8f4e5c2fb8d473c69a3b14983583332738d33372/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h#L184).

Error code -210 is defined as:

```
CV_StsUnsupportedFormat= -210, /**< the data format/type is not supported by the function*/
```

So, you'll need to coerce your image into `uint8` data type before passing it to `cv2.threshold`. This can be done with numpy using the `astype` method:

```
afterFourier = afterFourier.astype(np.uint8)
```

This will truncate all of the float values in `afterFourier` to 8 bit values, so you may want to do some scaling/rounding to the array before you do this, depending on your application.